# Max Lat, Min Lat, Max Long, Min Long from Geometry field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, gis

I'm trying to figure out how to get the max and min values for lat and long points from a geometry data field. I'm guessing you have to first convert it to a string us STAsText but I'm not sure. Let me know if you have any better idea?

Comment: Given that longitude is essentially a measure of a position on a circle, with an arbitrary 0 point, how meaningful is it to compute a min and max over it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different approach. 
1. I converted the geometry field to a string
2. Parsed the string and converted it to XML 
3. Stored it in a separate field
4. Ran an xml query off of that field.

The geom field in my case is storing areas for cities. In some cases the areas do not overlap, so actually have separate areas.

Here is the query I used to convert to XML.

```
update city set geomxml =  '<city>' +  replace(replace(replace(replace
 (replace(replace(replace   
             (geom.ToString(),'POLYGON ',''),
                    '((','<area><point><long>'),
                    '(','<area><point><long>'),
                    '))','</lat></point></area>'),
                    '), ','</lat></point></area>'),
                    ', ','</lat></point><point><long>'),
                    ' ','</long><lat>') +
                    '</city>'
```

Here is the query to get the max and min for lat and long

```
select geomxml.query('max(//lat)') as maxlat, geomxml.query('min(//lat)') as minlat, geomxml.query('max(//long)') as maxlong, geomxml.query('min(//long)') as minlong
from city
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the SQL Server extension methods "[Lat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933806.aspx)" and "[Long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933958.aspx)"  combined with Max and Min.

---

At first I read this as getting the min/max lat/long pair, and this was my answer: I suspect you could determine this by figuring out which point has the largest, and smallest distance from (0, 0), or whatever location you were concerned about.

Comment: The Lat and Long functions only work with Geography not Geometry (I believe).